# add a new item to vector and shift it remaining part to right

Tags: c++

I am trying to put a new item to vector, and shift remaining items. How can I do that ?

Ex

```
vector -------------------------------------------------------
       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 9 | 10 | 15 | 21 | 34 | 56 | 99 |
       -------------------------------------------------------
                                      ^
new item = 14, it should be added to  ^

After insertion, 


vector ------------------------------------------------------------
       | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 9 | 10 | 14 | 15 | 21 | 34 | 56 | 99 |
       ------------------------------------------------------------
                                         ^                         ^
                                         ^-shifted to right by one-^
```

Comment: I assume you are using `std::vector`.  I would look at the `insert()` function.  Are you trying to create your own vector class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [vector::insert()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function.

```
vector<int> vec ;

// Add elements to vec
vec.insert(vec.begin() + position, new_item);
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the link.  I will delete my answer.

Comment: Do not use cplucplus. look at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com

Comment: An alternate reference can be found at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) (or in the [language standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=50372) or similar [draft standards](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) -- see the [committee website](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/)).

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert`.

```
vector<int> v {1,2,3,5};
v.insert (v.begin() + 3, 4); //v is now {1,2,3,4,5}
```

You can also insert ranges of elements and other cool stuff, similar to the vector constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the exact position you want to insert it then `vec.insert()` is not going to work well.

```
vec.push_back(15);
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```